# そっち: "you" vs "over there"

Tags: meaning

How can I tell if そっち/そちら is used in the sense "you" or in the sense "over in your direction"?

For example:

> そっちの攻撃は 効かないよ 毒竜さん

Which of the meanings is more likely: "Your attacks won't work" or "The attacks coming from where you are / from your side won't work"?

Comment: Is it necessary to distinguish these two senses?  In English, we do want to know.  But in Japanese, there's an acceptable ambiguity here.  More context is probably necessary to say with certainty whether the attack in coming directly from the person being addressed or merely for their side.

Comment: as in many languages, context is important. No need to overthink it.

Comment: It could as well refer to where the attacks are directed at.